# How to return all paths with Breadth First Search without printing?

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I am trying to print all paths from source= 2 to destination = 3 with a graph that has the following edges:

```
g.addEdge(0, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 2) 
g.addEdge(0, 3) 
g.addEdge(2, 0) 
g.addEdge(2, 1) 
g.addEdge(1, 3)
```

When I print the variable "all_paths", it prints all possible paths correctly.
However, when I try to append this result to a list ("all_paths"), it returns a list of empty list.

See the part in the code:

```
        if u == d:
            all_paths.append(path)
            print(path)
```

print(path) prints:

```
    [2, 0, 1, 3]
    [2, 0, 3]
    [2, 1, 3]
```

The code returns:

```
[[], [], []]
```

It probably has something to do with the recursion but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I would like to return a list that contains:

```
[[2, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 0, 3],
[2, 1, 3]]
```

Below you can view the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
  
# This class represents a directed graph
# using adjacency list representation
class Graph:
  
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        # No. of vertices
        self.V = vertices
         
        # default dictionary to store graph
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)
  
    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)
  
    '''A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'.
    visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path.
    path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current
    index in path[]'''
    def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path, all_paths):
 
        # Mark the current node as visited and store in path
        visited[u]= True
        path.append(u)
 
        # If current vertex is same as destination, then print
        # current path[]
        if u == d:
            all_paths.append(path)
            print(path)
        else:
            # If current vertex is not destination
            # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
            for i in self.graph[u]:
                if visited[i]== False:
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path, all_paths)
        
        # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited
        path.pop()
        visited[u]= False
        
        return all_paths
        
  
    # Prints all paths from 's' to 'd'
    def printAllPaths(self, s, d):
 
        # Mark all the vertices as not visited
        visited =[False]*(self.V)
 
        # Create an array to store paths
        path = []
     
        all_paths = []
        
        # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths
        all_paths = self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path, all_paths)
      
        print(all_paths)
        return all_paths

g = Graph(4) 
g.addEdge(0, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 2) 
g.addEdge(0, 3) 
g.addEdge(2, 0) 
g.addEdge(2, 1) 
g.addEdge(1, 3) 
   
s = 2 ; d = 3
print (" These are the all unique paths from node %d to %d : " %(s, d)) 
g.printAllPaths(s, d)
```

I also tried to store it in a self.all_paths but this did not work.
I was expecting that when appending the path to all_paths it would work.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I am new to stackoverflow sorry about the tags, I changed it. Do you know how to solve my problem? Should I formulate it better?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing:

```
if u == d:
    all_paths.append(path)
    print(path)
```

to

```
if u == d:
    print(path)
    path2 = copy.deepcopy(path)
    all_paths.append(path2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious when you run it through [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=from%20collections%20import%20defaultdict%0A%20%20%0A%23%20This%20class%20represents%20a%20directed%20graph%0A%23%20using%20adjacency%20list%20representation%0Aclass%20Graph%3A%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20vertices%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20No.%20of%20vertices%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.V%20%3D%20vertices%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20default%20dictionary%20to%20store%20graph%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.graph%20%3D%20defaultdict%28list%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20function%20to%20add%20an%20edge%20to%20graph%0A%20%20%20%20def%20addEdge%28self,%20u,%20v%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.graph%5Bu%5D.append%28v%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%27%27%27A%20recursive%20function%20to%20print%20all%20paths%20from%20%27u%27%20to%20%27d%27.%0A%20%20%20%20visited%5B%5D%20keeps%20track%20of%20vertices%20in%20current%20path.%0A%20%20%20%20path%5B%5D%20stores%20actual%20vertices%20and%20path_index%20is%20current%0A%20%20%20%20index%20in%20path%5B%5D%27%27%27%0A%20%20%20%20def%20printAllPathsUtil%28self,%20u,%20d,%20visited,%20path,%20all_paths%29%3A%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Mark%20the%20current%20node%20as%20visited%20and%20store%20in%20path%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20visited%5Bu%5D%3D%20True%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path.append%28u%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20If%20current%20vertex%20is%20same%20as%20destination,%20then%20print%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20current%20path%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20u%20%3D%3D%20d%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20all_paths.append%28path%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28path%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20If%20current%20vertex%20is%20not%20destination%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Recur%20for%20all%20the%20vertices%20adjacent%20to%20this%20vertex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20self.graph%5Bu%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20visited%5Bi%5D%3D%3D%20False%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.printAllPathsUtil%28i,%20d,%20visited,%20path,%20all_paths%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Remove%20current%20vertex%20from%20path%5B%5D%20and%20mark%20it%20as%20unvisited%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path.pop%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20visited%5Bu%5D%3D%20False%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20all_paths%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Prints%20all%20paths%20from%20%27s%27%20to%20%27d%27%0A%20%20%20%20def%20printAllPaths%28self,%20s,%20d%29%3A%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Mark%20all%20the%20vertices%20as%20not%20visited%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20visited%20%3D%5BFalse%5D*%28self.V%29%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Create%20an%20array%20to%20store%20paths%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20all_paths%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Call%20the%20recursive%20helper%20function%20to%20print%20all%20paths%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20all_paths%20%3D%20self.printAllPathsUtil%28s,%20d,%20visited,%20path,%20all_paths%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28all_paths%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20all_paths%0A%0Ag%20%3D%20Graph%284%29%20%0Ag.addEdge%280,%201%29%20%0Ag.addEdge%280,%202%29%20%0Ag.addEdge%280,%203%29%20%0Ag.addEdge%282,%200%29%20%0Ag.addEdge%282,%201%29%20%0Ag.addEdge%281,%203%29%20%0A%20%20%20%0As%20%3D%202%20%3B%20d%20%3D%203%0Aprint%20%28%22%20These%20are%20the%20all%20unique%20paths%20from%20node%20%25d%20to%20%25d%20%3A%20%22%20%25%28s,%20d%29%29%20%0Ag.printAllPaths%28s,%20d%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=128&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

You only have one object `path` which you remove the elements in place when you move to a new path so the final list is just a list of 3 copies of the same list. you need to make a new list for each path.